# Which domain should I authorize in my .htaccess to let google spreadsheet access files on my site

Tags: google, htaccess, apache

I use google spreadsheet feature that allows one to let an image be the content of a cell. The cell is defined by:

```
=image("http://www.example.com/my-pics/my-pic.jpg")
```

It works pretty well.

But, I don't want my pics to be public. So I added a `.htaccess` file in the `my-pics` directory of my web site. Here is the template I used

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <domain used by google-spreadsheet to get image>
```

My problem is that I don't know which domain I should allow? Do you have any idea?

EDIT: Just an idea, but I cannot test it on my own (I use the web server my ISP provides me and I don't have access to logs). If my `.htaccess` is simply

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

and that google spreadsheet tries to access the image, it should be logged somewhere on my web server that domain `some-google-linked-domain.com` has tried to access the file. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a quick test and got the following in my Apache access logs from adding an image to a Google Spreadsheet:

```
64.233.172.188 - - [09/May/2014:05:14:51 -0700] "GET twitter.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1842 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html)"
66.249.80.216 - - [09/May/2014:05:14:52 -0700] "GET twitter.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1842 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html)"
66.249.80.216 - - [09/May/2014:05:14:52 -0700] "GET twitter.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1842 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible) Feedfetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html)"
```

Interestingly, Google grabs the image three times. Aside from that, whitelisting the IP isn't going to work as Google has a lot of those ([200,000+](http://snurps.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-many-ip-addresses-does-google-have.html) apparently).

Based on this the best bet is to allow by the user-agent. This [isn't foolproof](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg), but should be enough for your purposes. Naturally [StackExchange has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864727/htaccess-allow-all-from-specific-user-agent) already - so for what you're after, start with something like:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*Feedfetcher-Google.* search_robot

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=search_robot
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for digging into it. I'll go for that solution (provided google bots will not index my page bypassing my `robots.txt`). I thought that I wouldn't need to whitelist IPs, just domains.

Comment: You're welcome! You could filter on hostname, but doing the reverse lookup can bog your server down if it gets a bit of traffic.